# Form in a modal box is not posting on submiit

Tags: forms, modal-dialog

I have a contact form in a modal box and a php file to process the data and send it as an email.
For the life of me I can't get the modal to send any information -  it just closes as if nothing happened.
Here is the modal box code

```
<div id="quoteme" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel">  
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="boxmod">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text-center bfh-form-modal">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">×</button>
                    <form id="myForm" action="" method="POST" action="formtest.php">
                        <h1>Quick Quote</h1>
                        <p>Contact us today, and get a reply with in 24 hours!</p>
                        <fieldset>
                            <input class="monicker" name="name" placeholder="Your name" type="text" tabindex="1" required>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                            <input placeholder="Your Email Address" name="email" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                            <input placeholder="Your Phone Number" name="telnum" type="tel" tabindex="3" required>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                            <input placeholder="Your Web Site starts with http://" name="userurl" type="url" tabindex="4" required>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                            <textarea placeholder="Type your Message Here. To save time, please include as much detail as possible about the work you wish us to quote on." name="comments" tabindex="5" required></textarea>
                        </fieldset>
                        <fieldset>
                            <input name="submitbutton" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending" value="Submit"></input>
                        </fieldset>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I missing to make this send information to formtest.php?

Comment: First of all you have double definition of `action` in the `form` tag: `<form id="myForm" action="" method="POST" action="formtest.php">`

Comment: Ack!  Well spotted :)

Comment: Thank you Ignacy.  
I'm suitably embarrassed.  You would not believe how many hours I've wasted today for not spotting that. :)

Comment: Hmmm... and now I have no idea how to make mark your answer as correct.
Maybe I should just give  up on all this internet malarkey.

Comment: No worries, you can just post my comment as an answer and accept yourself. You can also upvote my comment. I'm glad I could help :)